# PWA foreground push notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

i have a problem with foreground push notifications.

I just want to get the data in the console for the moment but it didn't work. I follow the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) on firebase documentation but this function is never triggered...

```js
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});
```

Background notifications works as expected.

Here is my VueJs file

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/messaging';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("");

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted() {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => { // Don't work here
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    });

    this.getMsgPushToken();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('auth', ['mutMsgPushToken']),

    getMsgPushToken() {
      let that = this
      messaging.requestPermission().then(async function() {
        messaging.getToken().then((token) => {
          that.mutMsgPushToken(token); // Where i get the FCM token
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

And my service worker

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': ''
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

If you have any idea of what i'm missing, i would love to hear it ha ha

Comment: Can you share your body request to trigger the notification?
I have the same problem but I'm using Angualr ts

Comment: @DemoDemo i find my answer, the version of firebase import via CDN in the service worker is different than the firebase package via NPM. After settings the service worker to 7.7.0 (same as npm) it works as expected. Hope it can help you

Comment: I tried to update the libs to 7.7.0 but it did not fix the issue. I'm actually use https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send instead of
https://fcm.googleapis.com//v1/projects/<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>/messages:send
I want to get notifications without signing in to my gmail account.

Comment: Here's an answer with the most recent firebase version (9.12.1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824118/firebase-cloud-messaging-foreground-notification-not-working-in-vue/74116026#74116026